# UISegmentedControl in the Navigation Bar with the Back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm adding a `UISegmentedControl` to the Navigation bar programatically where the `titleView` should be. But as [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) have mentioned under `titleView`, *This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil*.

But I want to have the back button as well. Like they have illustrated in their own images!

[image]

Below is the code I add the `UISegmentedControl`.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Filter_Personnal", @"Filter_Department", @"Filter_Company", nil];
[statFilter setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = statFilter;
```

Is there another way to add a `UISegmentedControl` along with the Back button as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

Remove this line --- > `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`

Add this instead

```
UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Filter_Personnal", @"Filter_Department", @"Filter_Company", nil]];
[statFilter setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[statFilter sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = statFilter;
```

Only change is I have added this line :

```
[statFilter sizeToFit];
```

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: `setegmentedControlStyle` is deprecated as of iOS7... can you update your answer please?

Comment: This doesn't seems to work with segment control add via a IBOutlet. A segment control work added programatically work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view which could potentially be your `UISegmentedControl`.

Something along the lines of the following may work.

```
//create segmented control with items
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];

//create bar button item with segmented control as custom view
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

//add segmented control bar button item to navigation bar
[[[self navigationController] navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

I haven't tested this but it should be along the right lines of what you need.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. In the meantime I was waiting, I slapped together a small program to test it out. I put 2 View Controllers, a button in the first one to segue to the other one. And in the ViewDidLoad method of the second View Controller, I created the UISegmentedControl using the code I've posted in my question and [voila](http://i.imgur.com/DlZuAwk.png)! It works! I don't know why Apple has said it won't work. :S